# vim終了時にイベントを起こしたい。

Tags: vim

:wqとかでvimを終了した際に
「今日もお疲れ様」などをshellのsayコマンドを通して
鳴らしたいのですが、どうすれば良いでしょうか？

Answer (score 7, accepted):

以下のようなコードをvimrcに記述すればできると思います。
下記の例はWindowsでエクスプローラを起動する例ですが、Macなら「start explorer.exe」の部分を「open say "今日もお疲れ様"」のような感じ（未検証）でコマンドを記述すれば出来ると思います。

```
augroup quitcmd
  autocmd!
  autocmd VimLeave * :silent !start explorer.exe
augroup END
```

Answer (score 2):

解決されたようですが、別の方法も書いておきます。
以下のシェルスクリプトを path の通った場所に vim という名前で置きます。

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/vim "$@"
say '今日もお疲れ様'
```

vim の知識がなくてもできます。
say の行を aplay に変えれば、例えば Linux で音を鳴らすくらいはできるでしょう。